# Why doesn't my LCD work?

Tags: c, lcd, tft, stm32f10x

I have an 2.8" LCD that it's controller is [ILI9325](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9325.pdf). I'm trying to use it. for start off, I have written a simple program. the program is this:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "ILI9325.h"

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t b,c;

    Lcd_Configuration();
    Lcd_Initialize();
    Lcd_Clear(0xffff);
    Lcd_Clear(0x0000);
    Lcd_Clear(0xff00);
    for ( b = 0 ; b < 200 ; b++ )
    {
        for ( c = 0 ; c < 200 ; c++ )
        {
            DrawPixel( b , c , 0xffff );
        }       
    }

    test_color();

    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1)
    {

  }
}
```

The `ILI9325.h` is:

```
#ifndef __ILI9325_H 
#define __ILI9325_H 

// ILI9320 or ILI9325 
#define  ILI9325  


#define ID_AM  110 
extern u16 q; 

//#define Delay //Display Delay//Immediately 

#define Set_Cs  GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_8); 
#define Clr_Cs  GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_8); 

#define Set_Rs  GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_9); 
#define Clr_Rs  GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_9); 

#define Set_nWr GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_10); 
#define Clr_nWr GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_10); 

#define Set_nRd GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_11); 
#define Clr_nRd GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_11); 

#define Set_Rst GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_12); 
#define Clr_Rst GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_12); 

#define Lcd_Light_ON   GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_13); 
#define Lcd_Light_OFF  GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_13); 

typedef union 
{ 
  u16 U16; 
  u8 U8[2]; 
}ColorTypeDef; 


void Lcd_Configuration(void); 
void DataToWrite(u16 data); 
void LCD_WR_REG(u16 Index,u16 CongfigTemp);
void Lcd_Initialize(void); 
void Lcd_WR_Start(void); 
void Lcd_SetCursor(u8 x,u16 y); 
void Lcd_Clear(u16 Color); 
void Lcd_ClearCharBox(u8 x,u16 y,u16 Color); 
void DrawPixel(u16 x, u16 y, int Color);
void Lcd_SetBox(u8 xStart,u16 yStart,u8 xLong,u16 yLong,u16 x_offset,u16 y_offset); 
void Lcd_ColorBox(u8 x,u16 y,u8 xLong,u16 yLong,u16 Color); 
void test_color(void);

void Delay_nms(int n); 
//u16 Read9325(void); 

#endif
```

and the `ILI9325.c` is:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"   
#include "ILI9325.h"

u16 q;

/****************************************************************  

PB8--PB15
PC0--PC7
PC8 --> Lcd_cs  
PC9 --> Lcd_rs*  
PC10 --> Lcd_wr  
PC11 --> Lcd_rd*  
PC12 --> Lcd_rst  
PC13 --> Lcd_blaklight

*****************************************************************/

void Lcd_Configuration(void)   
{    
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;   

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA|RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB|RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);     

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8|GPIO_Pin_9|GPIO_Pin_10|GPIO_Pin_11|GPIO_Pin_12|GPIO_Pin_13|GPIO_Pin_14|GPIO_Pin_15;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0|GPIO_Pin_1|GPIO_Pin_2|GPIO_Pin_3|GPIO_Pin_4|GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_6|GPIO_Pin_7;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8|GPIO_Pin_9|GPIO_Pin_10|GPIO_Pin_11|GPIO_Pin_12;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =GPIO_Pin_13;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);   
} 



void DataToWrite(u16 data)    
{   
    u16 temp;   
    temp = GPIO_ReadOutputData(GPIOB);   
    GPIO_Write(GPIOB, (data<<8)|(temp&0x00ff));   
    temp = GPIO_ReadOutputData(GPIOC);   
    GPIO_Write(GPIOC, (data>>8)|(temp&0xff00));   
}

void LCD_WR_REG(u16 Index,u16 CongfigTemp)   
{   
    Clr_Cs;   
    Clr_Rs;   
    Set_nRd;   
    DataToWrite(Index);   
    Clr_nWr;   
    Set_nWr;   
    Set_Rs;          
    DataToWrite(CongfigTemp);          
    Clr_nWr;   
    Set_nWr;   
    Set_Cs;   
}

u16 CheckController(void)   
{   
    u16 tmp=0,tmp1=0,tmp2=0;    
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;   

    DataToWrite(0xffff);
    Set_Rst;   
    Set_nWr;   
    Set_Cs;   
    Set_Rs;   
    Set_nRd;   
    Set_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);   
    Clr_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);   
    Set_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0000,0x0001);  //start oscillation   
    Delay_nms(1);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8|GPIO_Pin_9|GPIO_Pin_10|GPIO_Pin_11|GPIO_Pin_12|GPIO_Pin_13|GPIO_Pin_14|GPIO_Pin_15;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0|GPIO_Pin_1|GPIO_Pin_2|GPIO_Pin_3|GPIO_Pin_4|GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_6|GPIO_Pin_7;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_8);   

    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_9);   

    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_11);   

    tmp1 = GPIO_ReadInputData(GPIOB);   
    tmp2 = GPIO_ReadInputData(GPIOC);   

    tmp = (tmp1>>8) | (tmp2<<8);   

    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_11);   

    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC,GPIO_Pin_8);   


    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8|GPIO_Pin_9|GPIO_Pin_10|GPIO_Pin_11|GPIO_Pin_12|GPIO_Pin_13|GPIO_Pin_14|GPIO_Pin_15;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;   
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0|GPIO_Pin_1|GPIO_Pin_2|GPIO_Pin_3|GPIO_Pin_4|GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_6|GPIO_Pin_7;   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

    return tmp;   
}



void Lcd_Initialize(void)   
{   
    u16 i;
    Lcd_Light_ON;   
    DataToWrite(0xffff);
    Set_Rst;   
    Set_nWr;   
    Set_Cs;   
    Set_Rs;   
    Set_nRd;   
    Set_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);   
    Clr_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);   
    Set_Rst;   
    Delay_nms(1);    

/*        
#ifdef ILI9325          
    LCD_WR_REG(0x00e3,0x3008);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x00e7,0x0010);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x00ef,0x1231);  //Set the internal vcore voltage  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0001,0x0100);  //When SS = 0, the shift direction of outputs is from S1 to S720                                  
#endif                          //When SS = 1, the shift direction of outputs is from S720 to S1.  
#ifdef ILI9320  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x00e5,0x8000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0000,0x0001);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0001,0x0100);//S  
    Delay_nms(10);  
#endif          
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0002,0x0700);//Line inversion          
#if   ID_AM==000         
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0000);
#elif ID_AM==001          
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0008);        
#elif ID_AM==010    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0010);          
#elif ID_AM==011  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0018);  
#elif ID_AM==100    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0020);        
#elif ID_AM==101    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0028);        
#elif ID_AM==110    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0030);        
#elif ID_AM==111    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,0x0038);  
#endif        
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0004,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0008,0x0207);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0009,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x000a,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x000c,0x0001);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x000d,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x000f,0x0000);        

    LCD_WR_REG(0x0010,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0011,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0012,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0013,0x0000);  
    Delay_nms(200);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0010,0x17b0);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0011,0x0137);  
    Delay_nms(50);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0012,0x0139);  
    Delay_nms(50);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0013,0x1700);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0029,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x002b,0x0000);  
    Delay_nms(50);        
#if   ID_AM==000           
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x00ef);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x013f);        
#elif ID_AM==001  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x00ef);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x013f);        
#elif ID_AM==010  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x013f);        
#elif ID_AM==011  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x013f);         
#elif ID_AM==100  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x00ef);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);        
#elif ID_AM==101    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x00ef);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);        
#elif ID_AM==110  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);        
#elif ID_AM==111  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);           
#endif         
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0030,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0031,0x0507);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0032,0x0104);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0035,0x0105);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0036,0x0404);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0037,0x0603);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0038,0x0004);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0039,0x0007);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x003c,0x0501);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x003d,0x0404);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,0x0000);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,0x00ef);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,0x0000);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,0x013f);
#ifdef ILI9325          
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0060,0xa700);//G  
#endif  
#ifdef ILI9320          
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0060,0x2700);//G    
#endif      
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0061,0x0001);//Enables the grayscale inversion of the image by setting REV=1.??????????????????????????????  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x006a,0x0000);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0080,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0081,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0082,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0083,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0084,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0085,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0090,0x0010);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0092,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0093,0x0003);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0095,0x0110);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0097,0x0000);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0098,0x0000);       

    LCD_WR_REG(0x0007,0x0130);  
#ifdef Immediately  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0007,0x0173);        
#endif            
       */
    i = CheckController();   
    q=i;        
    if(i==0x9325||i==0x9328)   
    {   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x00e7,0x0010);         
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0000,0x0001);              //start internal osc   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0001,0x0100);        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0002,0x0700);              //power on sequence                        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0003,(1<<12)|(1<<5)|(1<<4) );    //65K    
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0004,0x0000);                                      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0008,0x0207);                
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0009,0x0000);            
        LCD_WR_REG(0x000a,0x0000);              //display setting            
        LCD_WR_REG(0x000c,0x0001);              //display setting             
        LCD_WR_REG(0x000d,0x0000);              //0f3c             
        LCD_WR_REG(0x000f,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0010,0x0000);      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0011,0x0007);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0012,0x0000);                                                                    
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0013,0x0000);                    
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0010,0x1590);      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0011,0x0227);   
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0012,0x009c);                    
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0013,0x1900);      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0029,0x0023);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x002b,0x000e);   
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);                                                               
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);                    

        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0030,0x0007);    
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0031,0x0707);      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0032,0x0006);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0035,0x0704);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0036,0x1f04);    
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0037,0x0004);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0038,0x0000);           
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0039,0x0706);        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x003c,0x0701);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x003d,0x000f);   
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,0x0000);           
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,0x00ef);      
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,0x0000);        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,0x013f);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0060,0xa700);           
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0061,0x0001);    
        LCD_WR_REG(0x006a,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0080,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0081,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0082,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0083,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0084,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0085,0x0000);   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x0090,0x0010);        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0092,0x0000);     
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0093,0x0003);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0095,0x0110);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0097,0x0000);           
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0098,0x0000);     
         //display on sequence        
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0007,0x0133);   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x0020,0x0000);                                                               
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0021,0x0000);   
    }   
    else if(i==0x9320)   
    {   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x00,0x0000);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x01,0x0100);    //Driver Output Contral.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x02,0x0700);    //LCD Driver Waveform Contral.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x03,0x1030);    //Entry Mode Set.   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x04,0x0000);    //Scalling Contral.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x08,0x0202);    //Display Contral 2.(0x0207)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x09,0x0000);    //Display Contral 3.(0x0000)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0a,0x0000);    //Frame Cycle Contal.(0x0000)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0c,(1<<0));  //Extern Display Interface Contral 1.(0x0000)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0d,0x0000);    //Frame Maker Position.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x0f,0x0000);    //Extern Display Interface Contral 2.   

        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x07,0x0101);    //Display Contral.   
        for(i=50000;i>0;i--);   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x10,(1<<12)|(0<<8)|(1<<7)|(1<<6)|(0<<4)); //Power Control 1.(0x16b0)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x11,0x0007);                                //Power Control 2.(0x0001)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x12,(1<<8)|(1<<4)|(0<<0));                    //Power Control 3.(0x0138)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x13,0x0b00);                                //Power Control 4.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x29,0x0000);                                //Power Control 7.   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x2b,(1<<14)|(1<<4));   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x50,0);     //Set X Start.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x51,239);   //Set X End.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x52,0);     //Set Y Start.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x53,319);   //Set Y End.   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x60,0x2700);    //Driver Output Control.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x61,0x0001);    //Driver Output Control.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x6a,0x0000);    //Vertical Srcoll Control.   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x80,0x0000);    //Display Position? Partial Display 1.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x81,0x0000);    //RAM Address Start? Partial Display 1.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x82,0x0000);    //RAM Address End-Partial Display 1.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x83,0x0000);    //Displsy Position? Partial Display 2.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x84,0x0000);    //RAM Address Start? Partial Display 2.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x85,0x0000);    //RAM Address End? Partial Display 2.   

        LCD_WR_REG(0x90,(0<<7)|(16<<0));    //Frame Cycle Contral.(0x0013)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x92,0x0000);    //Panel Interface Contral 2.(0x0000)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x93,0x0001);    //Panel Interface Contral 3.   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x95,0x0110);    //Frame Cycle Contral.(0x0110)   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x97,(0<<8));  //   
        LCD_WR_REG(0x98,0x0000);    //Frame Cycle Contral.   


        LCD_WR_REG(0x07,0x0173);    //(0x0173)   
    }   
}   



void Lcd_WR_Start(void)   
{   
    Clr_Cs;   
    Clr_Rs;   
    Set_nRd;   
    DataToWrite(0x0022);   
    Clr_nWr;   
    Set_nWr;   
    Set_Rs;   
}  



void Lcd_SetCursor(u8 x,u16 y)   
{    
    LCD_WR_REG(0x20,x);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x21,y);       
} 



void Lcd_Clear(u16 Color)   
{   
    u32 temp;   

    Lcd_SetCursor(0x00, 0x0000);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,0x00);  
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,239);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,0x00); 
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,319);     
    Lcd_WR_Start();   
    Set_Rs;   

    for (temp = 0; temp < 76800; temp++)   
    {   
        DataToWrite(Color);   
        Clr_nWr;   
        Set_nWr;   
    }   

    Set_Cs;   
}   



void Lcd_SetBox(u8 xStart,u16 yStart,u8 xLong,u16 yLong,u16 x_offset,u16 y_offset)   
{   

#if ID_AM==000       
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+xLong-1+x_offset,yStart+yLong-1+y_offset);   

#elif ID_AM==001   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+xLong-1+x_offset,yStart+yLong-1+y_offset);   

#elif ID_AM==010   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+x_offset,yStart+yLong-1+y_offset);   

#elif ID_AM==011    
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+x_offset,yStart+yLong-1+y_offset);   

#elif ID_AM==100   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+xLong-1+x_offset,yStart+y_offset);        

#elif ID_AM==101   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+xLong-1+x_offset,yStart+y_offset);        

#elif ID_AM==110   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+x_offset,yStart+y_offset);    

#elif ID_AM==111   
    Lcd_SetCursor(xStart+x_offset,yStart+y_offset);     

#endif   

    LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,xStart+x_offset); 
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,xStart+xLong-1+x_offset);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,yStart+y_offset); 
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,yStart+yLong-1+y_offset);  
}   


void Lcd_ColorBox(u8 xStart,u16 yStart,u8 xLong,u16 yLong,u16 Color)   
{   
    u32 temp;   

    Lcd_SetBox(xStart,yStart,xLong,yLong,0,0);   
    Lcd_WR_Start();   
    Set_Rs;   

    for (temp=0; temp<xLong*yLong; temp++)   
    {   
        DataToWrite(Color);   
        Clr_nWr;   
        Set_nWr;   
    }   

    Set_Cs;   
}   


void Lcd_ClearCharBox(u8 x,u16 y,u16 Color)   
{   
    u32 temp;   

    Lcd_SetBox(x*8,y*16,8,16,0,0);    
    Lcd_WR_Start();   
    Set_Rs;   

    for (temp=0; temp < 128; temp++)   
    {   
        DataToWrite(Color);    
        Clr_nWr;   
        //Delay_nus(22);   
        Set_nWr;    
    }   

    Set_Cs;   
}   




void Delay_nms(int n)   
{   

  u32 f=n,k;   
  for (; f!=0; f--)   
  {   
    for(k=0xFFF; k!=0; k--);   
  }   

}   
void DrawPixel(u16 x, u16 y, int Color)   
{   
    Lcd_SetCursor(x,y);   
    Lcd_WR_Start();    
    Set_Rs;   
    DataToWrite(Color);   
    Clr_nWr;   
    Set_nWr;                                 
    Set_Cs;   
}   
void DispPic240_320(const unsigned char *str)   
{   

    u32 temp;   
    ColorTypeDef color;   
    Lcd_SetCursor(0x00, 0x0000);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,0x00);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,239);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,0);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,319);   
    Lcd_WR_Start();   
    Set_Rs;   

    for (temp = 0; temp < 240*320; temp++)   
    {     
        color.U8[1] =*(unsigned short *)(&str[ 2 * temp]);   
        color.U8[0]=*(unsigned short *)(&str[ 2 * temp+1]);   
        //DataToWrite(i);   

        DataToWrite(color.U16);   
        Clr_nWr;   
        Set_nWr;   
    }   

//==============================     
}   
void test_color(void){   
  u8  R_data,G_data,B_data,i,j;   

    Lcd_SetCursor(0x00, 0x0000);   
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0050,0x00);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0051,239);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0052,0);
    LCD_WR_REG(0x0053,319); 
    Lcd_WR_Start();   
    Set_Rs;   
    R_data=0;G_data=0;B_data=0;        
    for(j=0;j<50;j++)
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {R_data=i/8;DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;Set_nWr;}   
    }   
    R_data=0x1f;G_data=0x3f;B_data=0x1f;   
    for(j=0;j<50;j++)   
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {   
            G_data=0x3f-(i/4);   
            B_data=0x1f-(i/8);   
            DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;   
            Set_nWr;   
            }   
    }   
//----------------------------------   
    R_data=0;G_data=0;B_data=0;   
    for(j=0;j<50;j++)
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {G_data=i/4;   
            DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;   
            Set_nWr;}   
    }   

    R_data=0x1f;G_data=0x3f;B_data=0x1f;   
    for(j=0;j<50;j++)   
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {   
            R_data=0x1f-(i/8);   
            B_data=0x1f-(i/8);   
            DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;   
            Set_nWr;   
        }   
    }   
//----------------------------------   

    R_data=0;G_data=0;B_data=0;   
    for(j=0;j<60;j++)  
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {B_data=i/8;DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;   
            Set_nWr;}   
    }    

    B_data=0;    
    R_data=0x1f;G_data=0x3f;B_data=0x1f;   

    for(j=0;j<60;j++)   
    {   
        for(i=0;i<240;i++)   
            {   
            G_data=0x3f-(i/4);   
            R_data=0x1f-(i/8);   
            DataToWrite(R_data<<11|G_data<<5|B_data);   
            Clr_nWr;   
            Set_nWr;   
        }   
    }        
    Set_Cs;   
}
```

All pins of the LCD are connected to MCU and supply like this schematic:

```
VCC-------->3.3v
GND-------->GND
LED_VCC---->3.3v
LED_GND---->GND
Y(-)------->not connected
Y(+)------->not connected
X(-)------->not connected
X(+)------->not connected
IM0-------->not connected
RD--------->PC13
WR--------->PC10
RS--------->PC9
CS--------->PC8
RSt-------->PC12
(D1-D8)---->(PC0-PC7)
(D10-D17)-->(PB8-PB15)
```

As you can see its interface is 16bit. for 16bit interface, if you see page 10 of ILI9325's datasheet you will see this:

[image: figure1]

And page 26:

[image: figure2]

But lone `IM[3:0]` pin that I can see is `IM0`. by the way I think my circuit should work but when I trun on the circuit, lone thing that I can see is this:

[image: figre3]

Just a white background! damn it! What's the problem? in your opinion why doesn't my circuit(LCD) work?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a thousand reasons why the LCD is not working.

It could be one of these for starters:

1. Not fully understanding the documentation.
2. A connection problem.
3. Any one of a number of problems with the software algorithm.
4. A signal timing problem of not meeting protocol requirements at the display.
5. A signal integrity problem due to voltage level errors, ringing on signal lines due to long wires or power suppply issues.
6. Improper treatment of the LCD bias voltages. Especially a problem if generated on board but require proper capacitors attached to some signal pins and the bias generator to be configured properly.

I can tell you from direct experience that it is a rare day that firing up a new LCD module, particularly graphics ones, will just start working. It can be a slow and painstaking process.

One of the first things that you have to do is to work at a very low level and make sure that all the interface signals look good and have correct timing.

Next try to convince yourself that you are actually communicating with the display controller. This can sometimes be done by writing some register and then reading it back to see that the written bit values come back. Other times it may be necessary to write one register and then read back the BUSY status to see that it toggles to BUSY and then back to not busy.

Comment: Ok, I will check it again.

Comment: @Roh - For the low level investigation an oscilloscope is an essential tool. Also note that if any part of the display controller documentation is confusing or vague do not hesitate to bring it here as an additional question.

Comment: Thanks Michael. one vague part is that my LCD just have IM0. I mean I cannot find IM1, IM2 and IM3 pins on my LCD's pin-out. in fact I don't know why there are not IM1, IM2 and IM3!?

Comment: I suspect that you are seeing the IM0 -> IM3 pins in the LCD controller chip data sheet. However you find the singular IM0 on the range of connection pins to the LCD module. It is very common that the designer of a module board (or LCD glass in case of a COG type display) to tie off certain chip pins (high or low) to configure the chip so that it is specific to module design. If the module manufacturer has done a decent job they will document this in their module data sheet - but often the module documentation sucks and you have to figure out things by experiment.

Comment: @Roh - Another thing to consider...I see that a large amount of the code that you show appears to have come from someplace on the web. It is often that people post code that is not 100% working code. Also someone may have made code for a particular display controller IC chip but maybe they were using a different LCD module than you. There could be chip configuration differences from one module to the next. For both of these reasons it is really necessary to not trust any of the code that you downloaded and go through it with a fine comb and check and understand every line and every function.

Comment: Aaaammm... good point +1 Ok, let me to check the codes and its configuration. also it's not a module. it's an adaptor.